# Issue with table_query / __TABLES__

Tags: google-bigquery

I am facing a "Connection Error" issue with the table_query function, on one of my datasets

**Example 1)**

```
bq query "select * from (table_query([MYDOMAIN:MYPROJECT:MYDATASET], 'table_id contains \"20140522\"')) limit 1"
```

The above command always(100% reproducible) fails with error "BigQuery error in query operation: Connection error. Please try again.", after a minute or so.

But if I execute "bq ls -j",
  I can see that it actually launched bqjob_r1c258fa26faab850_00000147f479ed5d_1
  and that it really completed in 1 second.

Using "bq --format=prettyjson show -j bqjob_r1c258fa26faab850_00000147f479ed5d_1" and "bq head ....",
  I can read the output of the job as well.

**Example 2:**
  I am seeing 100% reproducible failures in querying the underlying **TABLES** table in this dataset as well.

```
bq query "select * from [MYDOMAIN:MYPROJECT:MYDATASET.__TABLES__] limit 1"
```

This also reports "BigQuery error in query operation: Connection error. Please try again."
  But "bq ls -j" shows me that it succesfully completed job bqjob_r7e6eabcd0a39541_00000147f482cf90_1 in 0 seconds.
  Like in previous example, I can use "bq head" to read the job output.

**The questions I have are:**

1) Why do the "command line tool(version 2.0.22), and the browser" always wait a long time after the job completed, and then lie to me that the job failed with "Connection error"?

2) Why does this "connection error" issue happen only with this particular dataset?